# PowerBook G4 (3,5) airport drivers

Tags: apple, powerpc

I'm looking for the airport drivers for my Powerbook G4 model 3,5 [(link)](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powerbook_g4/specs/powerbook_g4_867.html) Where can i find those?

Comment: This is answered well in the PowerPC wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ#Will_my_wireless_work.3F

Answer (score 0):

Broadcom, that makes the wifi chipset for the airport, only releases x86 non-free drivers for linux. So getting the wifi to work is unlikely. Broadcom supposedly is now producing an open source driver but I think the hardware it supports is limited to new hardware. (it is also only in kernels newer than Precise)